# How do I make HTTP Authentication work with MAMP using php 5.6.2

Tags: php, http, authentication, http-authentication

I am following "Learning PHP.MySQL,JS," by Robin Nixon and came at HTTP AUTHENTICATION process. For a week, I have been trying to make it work but no luck. I am using MAMP and problem seems to be with the interface 'cgi'. I used the **php_sapi_name()** function that returned apache2handler (which I think is a php mode) and not cgi. I am using php 5.6.2. This is what I wrote in .htaccess file and saved it in the same folder as the php script:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my PHP script httpAuthentication.php :

```
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])
{
   echo "Welcome User: " . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . "Pass: " .   $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
}

else
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die("Please enter your username and password");
}
```

The page does not display anything. Any help will be appreciated!